# How can I use a C library in an Cordova based Android app

Tags: android, c, cordova, android-ndk

I'm writing an android application with cordova that requires the use of an existing C library for deserializing binary data.

I believe I need to create a cordova plugin to write a javascript wrapper to access android's native java and utilize NDK, however I have no idea how to go about doing it. I have no experience writing cordova plugins, let alone one that uses NDK.

Could anyone give me a walk through or even better a simple example plugin that achieves this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a lot of research and I think I figured things out, I made a repo to help anyone else that needed a simple example to learn from: https://github.com/clement360/Cordova-Hello-JNI-Plugin